# Can I use some of the spring batch writers to write into single line txt file?

Tags: spring-batch

can i use some of the spring batch writers to write into single line text file containing multiple 512 bytes long strings.

Regards

Comment: What is your use case? Is Spring Batch the right tool for the job?

Comment: will have multiple strings 512 bytes length and i should write them into txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the `FlatFileItemWriter` to write Strings to a file. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
        FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<String>()
                .name("writer")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("test.txt"))
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .build();

        writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
        writer.write(strings);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This is an example of using Spring Batch as a library, not as a framework. But I'm not sure you really need Spring Batch to write some strings to a file..